# PHPMailer siteground trouble with mail SMTP connection trouble

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

Please tell me how to make the phpmailer module work for siteground hosting?

I noticed that if I comment or remove `$mail->isSMTP();` this line, sending mail starts working. But this breaks the logic of my code, because I cannot display success message

Also works if i replace `$mail->isMail();` instead of  `$mail->isSMTP();`

Does this mean that SMTP is blocked by the hosting?

My PHPMailer SMTP Config is:

```
<?php
MAIL_FROM = 'MAIL_ACC_CREATED_ON_SITEGROUND.com',
MAIL_SMTP_HOST = 'mail.mydomain.com',
MAIL_SMTP_PORT = 465;
MAIL_SMTP_USERNAME = 'MAIL_ACC_CREATED_ON_SITEGROUND.com', 
MAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD = 'password'; 
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = MAIL_SMTP_HOST;
$mail->Port = MAIL_SMTP_PORT;
$mail->Username = MAIL_SMTP_USERNAME;
$mail->Password = MAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

I would be grateful for any tip and help!

Comment: Please enable Debug and try..
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing) // 1 = errors and messages // 2 = messages only

Comment: I added this line, but I do not see debug information in the browser, how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you added echo $mail->ErrorInfo; line?

Comment: `if (!$mail->send()) {` 
`$data['result'] = 'error';`
`log_write('Error sending email: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);`
`}`

And all i'll get is 
29.05.2021 07:28:03
`Error sending email: SMTP connect() failed. `https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting`
-------------------------

If i add `echo $mail->ErrorInfo;` nothing happens.
I have `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; `

Comment: In general, hosting technical support could not help me. Even using a third-party SMTP server, emails are not sent from gmail. Although with an identical configuration on the localhost, everything is sent. Any ideas guys?

Comment: We can’t tell from what you’ve said. Read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide to diagnose your issue

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how, but I fixed this problem. The problem was my code, not the hosting.